# How to import org.apache in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, xml-rpc

I need to add "import org.apache.*" to my ASP.NET application. Can you suggest me a way to do this. Thank you.

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;
```

Comment: What do you want to use `org.apache.*` for? It seems to be related to java code. If possible, I will help you find a relevant solution to your problem.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT  Yeah, ```import org.apache.*``` is the way of importing it in the java. I need to import apache to .net. I tried to find it in nuget packages, dll files. but not succeded.